# Syntax error when comparing directories

Tags: bash

I keep getting the following error when running the following command: **bash -
 syntax error near unexpected token `(`**.

```
A=/dev1/annemarie/
B=/home/annemarie/
diff -u <(find "$B" |sed "s:$B::") <(find "$A" | sed "s:$A::") | sed "/^+\//!d; s::$A/:"
```

or

```
diff -u <(find " B=/home/annemarie/" |sed "s: B=/home/annemarie/::") <(find "/dev1/annemarie/" | sed "s:/dev1/annemarie/::") | sed "/^+\//!d; s::/dev1/annemarie//:"
```

or

```
echo "diff -u <(find \"$B\" |sed \"s:$B::\") <(find \"$A\" | sed \"s:$A::\") | sed \"/^+\//!d; s::$A/:\" >> /tmp/$$.sh
```

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scripts with process substitution *must* be run via `bash`, not `sh`. Ensure that the shebang references `/bin/bash` and/or that the script is being passed to `bash` on the command line.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the question to include a second example. Is the syntax correct?

Comment: The syntax is fine *if you're not running bash in compatibility mode* (or if you're running, say, zsh presumably).

Comment: Hmm okay... and if I am not doing this, is there a way to make it compatible?

Comment: Temporary files.

Comment: I tried it and it still doesn't work. Error message is: `bash - syntax error near unexpected token (.`

Comment: What version of bash are you running?

Comment: Not sure. Just wrapped everything in `bash -c 'xxxxxx'` and it worked